# Subprocessing Data Loading in pytroch into Google Colab

Tags: subprocess, python-multiprocessing, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm working on training a deep neural network using `pytorch` and I use `DataLoader` for preprocessing data and multi-processing purpose over dataset. I set `num_workers` attribute to positive number like 4 and my `batch_size` is 8. I train network on `Google Colab` Environment but when training keep on after few minutes, stop training and get error in reading `.PNG` files. I think it's memory error and I want to know what is relation between **number of GPU** and **batch_size** and **num_workers** to set up a reasonable relation between them specially in **Google Colab** .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow this page:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1jxUPzMsAkBboHMQtGyfv5M5c7hU8Ss2c&scrollTo=EM7EnBoyK8nR

It provide a guide of how to set settings of Google Colab.

I try it and feels really fast.

Hope you love it.

Following is the code it provides but I change a bit about install pytorch:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import sys
sys.version

# http://pytorch.org/
from os import path
from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag
platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())

accelerator = 'cu80' if path.exists('/opt/bin/nvidia-smi') else 'cpu'

!pip install -q http://download.pytorch.org/whl/{accelerator}/torch-0.3.0.post4-{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl torchvision


import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.datasets as dsets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable

input_size    = 784   # The image size = 28 x 28 = 784
hidden_size   = 500   # The number of nodes at the hidden layer
num_classes   = 10    # The number of output classes. In this case, from 0 to 9
num_epochs    = 5     # The number of times entire dataset is trained
batch_size    = 100   # The size of input data took for one iteration
learning_rate = 1e-3  # The speed of convergence

train_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root='./data',
                           train=True,
                           transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                           download=True)

test_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root='./data',
                           train=False,
                           transform=transforms.ToTensor())

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(Net, self).__init__()                    # Inherited from the parent class nn.Module
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)  # 1st Full-Connected Layer: 784 (input data) -> 500 (hidden node)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()                          # Non-Linear ReLU Layer: max(0,x)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes) # 2nd Full-Connected Layer: 500 (hidden node) -> 10 (output class)

    def forward(self, x):                              # Forward pass: stacking each layer together
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out

net = Net(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes)

use_cuda = True

if use_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available():
    net.cuda()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):   # Load a batch of images with its (index, data, class)
        images = Variable(images.view(-1, 28*28))         # Convert torch tensor to Variable: change image from a vector of size 784 to a matrix of 28 x 28
        labels = Variable(labels)

        if use_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available():
            images = images.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()

        optimizer.zero_grad()                             # Intialize the hidden weight to all zeros
        outputs = net(images)                             # Forward pass: compute the output class given a image
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)                 # Compute the loss: difference between the output class and the pre-given label
        loss.backward()                                   # Backward pass: compute the weight
        optimizer.step()                                  # Optimizer: update the weights of hidden nodes

        if (i+1) % 100 == 0:                              # Logging
            print('Epoch [%d/%d], Step [%d/%d], Loss: %.4f'
                 %(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, len(train_dataset)//batch_size, loss.data[0]))


correct = 0
total = 0
for images, labels in test_loader:
    images = Variable(images.view(-1, 28*28))

    if use_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available():
        images = images.cuda()
        labels = labels.cuda()


    outputs = net(images)
    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)  # Choose the best class from the output: The class with the best score
    total += labels.size(0)                    # Increment the total count
    correct += (predicted == labels).sum()     # Increment the correct count

print('Accuracy of the network on the 10K test images: %d %%' % (100 * correct / total))

torch.save(net.state_dict(), 'fnn_model.pkl')
```